# After User clicks a Link and is redirected, how to make a function automatically activate

Tags: reactjs, redirect, scroll, react-hooks, use-state

With React, after the user has been redirected after clicking , a function needs to activate once the new page finishes loading. that function scrolls the user to the bottom of the web page. What I cant figure out is how to pass state with a  to tell receiving component to activate its function.

So basically user clicks on something like this..

```
  <Link 
    to="/"
    setState(true)
    >
    Contact
  </Link>
```

After being redirected, the newly loaded page has a function waiting for it like this..

```
const redirectTrigger = () =>{
          if (state == true){
            scrollToBottom()
          }
      }
```

But this seems impossible?

Comment: You should show any effort, what have you tried?

Comment: Well, as of right now I'm messing around with npm react-scroll, which works, but I cant figure out out to activate it after a user is redirected. 

I have managed to make it a clickable button that then scrolls the user to the contact page. Here is my working demo - https://eastside-wedding-videography.netlify.app/